# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am getting this error while trying to execute the attached code. Please help. I am getting values as list array in controller method successfully but when I try to read data from sql database I am getting error.

### Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult searchdata(List<string> firstField, List<string> secondField, List<string> thirdField)
        {
            List<string> lt = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine(firstField);
            Console.WriteLine(secondField);
            string dogCsv = string.Join(",", firstField.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(dogCsv);
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Srivatsava; integrated security=SSPI"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        command.CommandText = @"select accntname,BU,salesop,isdormant from fourth_page as fg
                                  INNER JOIN linked as ld on ld.productid=fg.productid 
                                   INNER JOIN isdormant as it on it.productid=ld.productid 
                                   where fg.accountname in (" + dogCsv + ")";
                        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstField", dogCsv);
                        using (SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {

                                lt.Add(sdr["accntname"].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(lt);
            return Json(firstField);

        }
```

### Execption:-

```
{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'account2'.
Invalid column name 'account1'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MvcApplication32.Controllers.TodoListController.searchdata(List`1 firstField, List`1 secondField, List`1 thirdField) in c:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication32\MvcApplication32\Controllers\TodoListController.cs:line 597
ClientConnectionId:a0674fe4-e0d5-499f-be61-66e1b27768fa}
```

Comment: Print out the SQL statement.  I'm 98% sure the answer will be obvious (missing quotes in the `IN` list).  If not, edit your question and include the statement after variable substitution.

Comment: Sql statement is executing properly. Could you please help me where can I place missing quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using inline SQL, every value within dogCSV string that's comma separated needs a single quote around it.  For instance, if dogCSV has `"account2,someotheraccount"`, this won't work it needs to be `"'account2','someotheraccount'"`.

If you don't that definitely would be the issue.

EDIT: Build dogCSV like this:

```
string dogCsv = string.Join(",", firstField.Select(i => "'" + i + "'"));
```

The way it's built now will not put quotes around it.

Comment: How to make every value as single quoted? @"select accntname,BU,salesop,isdormant from fourth_page as fg INNER JOIN linked as ld on ld.productid=fg.productid INNER JOIN isdormant as it on it.productid=ld.productid where fg.accountname in ('" + dogCsv + "')";

Comment: I have edited my query I think it is taking as accountname in ('account1,account2') like that, but it needs to be accountname in ('account1','account2'). How can make my code to get output like that?

Comment: In  your code above, it wouldn't put any quotes in.  Check out my edit.